# How to calculate the similarity of English words that do not appear in WordNet?

Tags: python, nltk, similarity

A particular natural language practice is to calculate the similarity between two words using WordNet. I start my question with the following python code:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
sport = wordnet.synsets("sport")[0]
badminton = wordnet.synsets("badminton")[0]
print(sport.wup_similarity(badminton))
```

We will get 0.8421

Now what if I look for "haha" and "lol" as following:

```
haha = wordnet.synsets("haha")
lol = wordnet.synsets("lol")
print(haha)
print(lol)
```

We will get

```
[]
[]
```

Then we cannot consider the similarity between them. What can we do in this case?

Comment: What kind of similarity are you trying to calculate?  Semantic similarity?  You won't be able to calculate it without some sort of database of word meanings (like WordNet).

Comment: What do you mean? I already use WordNet, the similarity is calculated using Wu-Palmer Similarity. Please carefully see the code.

Comment: Take a look at the STS task: http://alt.qcri.org/semeval2016/task1/ And a shameless plug: https://github.com/alvations/stasis

Answer (score 7):

You can create a semantic space from cooccurrence matrices using a tool like **Dissect** [(DIStributional SEmantics Composition Toolkit)](http://clic.cimec.unitn.it/composes/toolkit/)
and then you are set to measure semantic similarity between words or phrases (if you compose words).

In your case for *ha* and *lol* you'll need to collect those cooccurrences.

Another thing to try is word2vec.

Comment: Can you narrow down to some hints or some starting points that I can search myself?

Comment: I think an easy starting point is just to compute bigram collocations from your dataset, i.e. which word occurs next to another word very frequently. You will then find that e.g. *ha* and *lol* have very similar neighbors. Afaik that's the idea behind [word2vec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word2vec)  etc.

Answer (score 5):

There are two possible other ways:

CBOW: continuous bag of word

skip gram model: This model is vice versa of CBOW model

look at this: https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-continuous-bag-of-words-and-skip-gram-architectures-in-laymans-terms

These model are well represted here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/word2vec, also [GENSIM](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/) is a good python library for doing such these things

---

Try to look for [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) Solutions, For example this: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py

Or try to look for word2vec: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word2vec

Answer (score 2):

There are different models for measuring similarity, such as word2vec or glove, but you seem to be looking more for a corpus which includes social, informal phrases like 'lol'.

However, I'm going to bring up word2vec because it leads to what I think is an answer to your question.

The foundational concept of word2vec (and other word embedding models like glove) is the representation of words in a vector space which incorporates relationships between words.  This lends itself very well to measuring similarity, since vectors have lots of established math to draw from.  You can read more about the technical details of word2vec in the original [paper,](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5021-distributed-representations-of-words-and-phrases-and-their-compositionality.pdf) but I quite like [this blog post](http://mccormickml.com/2016/04/19/word2vec-tutorial-the-skip-gram-model/) because it is well-written and concise.

Again, since word2vec is just a model, you need to pair it with the right training set to get the kind of scope you seek.  There are some pre-trained models floating around on the web, such as [this bunch.](https://github.com/3Top/word2vec-api)  The training set is really what allows you to query a larger variety of terms, rather than the model.

You can certainly use those pre-trained models if they have social phrases like the ones you're seeking.  However, if you don't see a model that has been trained on a suitable corpus, you could easily train a model yourself.  I suggest Twitter or Wikipedia for corpora (training sets), and the implementation of word2vec in `gensim` as a word embedding model.

Answer (score 2):

You can use other frameworks. I was trying also NLTK but finally landed on spacy (spacy.io) very fast and functional framework. There is a method for words called 'similarity' which compers to other words(but it works also for sentences, docs etc). It is implemented using word2vec. Actually I don't know how big is their vocabulary and how it struggle in case the word is unknown but it might be worth to try.

I was also playing a little bit with this one:
https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html
Where in 2 lines you can load google's big word2vec model(this project ports google word2vec c++ library into python) accessible here:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7XkCwpI5KDYaDBDQm1tZGNDRHc/edit